# Symfony put form data into sfRequest in link submission

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Using Symfony I created a form in the backend. I have a submit button, which is used to save the form. I need to add another link (besides submit button) to the form that is supposed to send form data like submit button. Via this link I will be working on the submitted data via another method in the controller.

I have tried `link_to('Link', '/backend_dev.php/question/edit?id='.$question->getId(), array('post' => true))` and `link_to('Link', '/backend_dev.php/question/edit?id='.$question->getId(), array('method' => 'post'))`, but these functions do not send form data.

**Controller**

```
public function executeSave(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->form = new SomeForm(SomePeer::retrieveByPk($request->getParameter('id')));
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('some'), $request->getFiles('some'));
        if ($this->form->isValid())
        {
            $some = $this->form->save();
            $this->redirect('some/edit?id='.$some->getId());
        }
    }
}

public function executeLink(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    // Like executeSave I need form data here
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a link to submit a form ? It's the job of the submit button ...

Comment: I need the functionality to submit form and processed submitted data by two different methods. So I use submit button for the one, and try to put a submit link for the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery with an onClick event on the link which will change the `action` attribute of the form and submit it. Assuming the link has an id `myLink` and the form an id `myForm`:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e){
    $('#myForm').attr('action','<?php echo '/backend_dev.php/question/edit?id='.$question->getId()?>';
    $('#myForm').submit();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```